# c# .aspx page Record Navigation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I have a simple .aspx page with navigation buttons but though First & Last buttons work OK, Next & Previous only move between records 1 & 2 for some reason I cannot work out.
I am still a bit of a newcomer to C# and ASP.NET, but this seems so basic it's embarrassing!
I am using SQL Server 2012 and Visual Studio 2017.
It is strange because the record count confirms that all records have been read.

```
C# Code:
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        //
        SqlDataReader dr;
        DataSet ds;
        int recordcount = 0;
        int i;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ASPIREV17;Initial Catalog=dbSVCCAssets;Integrated Security=True");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ASPIREV17;Initial Catalog=dbSVCCAssets;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SignboardInspection", con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();

            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, "SignboardInspection");
            Response.Write("Connection is Open Now!!");
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            recordcount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            Response.Write("Record Count : " + recordcount);

            if (recordcount > i)
            {
                TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DateInspected"].ToString();
                TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NextInspection"].ToString();
                TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Comments"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ("No Records Returned");
            }
            dr.Read();

            con.Close();
            Response.Write("Connection is Closed Now!!");
        }

        protected void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                i = 0;
                TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DateInspected"].ToString();
                TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NextInspection"].ToString();
                TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Comments"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ("First Record");
            }
        }

        protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                i++;
                TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DateInspected"].ToString();
                TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NextInspection"].ToString();
                TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Comments"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ("This is the Last Record");
            }
        }

        protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (i == ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            i--;
            TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["DateInspected"].ToString();
            TextBox3.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["NextInspection"].ToString();
            TextBox4.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Comments"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
                lblMessage.Text = ("This is the First Record");
        }
    }
```

Please advise and be gentle!

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the variable i, for example in the Session dictionary, to hold its value, something like this

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = Convert.ToInt32(Session["i"].ToString());
    if (i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        i++;

        String s = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Image"].ToString();
        s = s.Trim();
        String path = "~/images/" + s + ".jpg";
        Image1.ImageUrl = path;

        Product.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Product"].ToString();
        Product_Id.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
        Cost.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Cost"].ToString();
        Category.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["Category"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ("This is the Last Record");
    }
    Session["i"] = i;
}
```